# Выборка строк с дублями

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql, выборка

Имеется таблица с полями: `номер сделки клиента`, `дата сделки клиента`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как произвести выборку из бд строк, в которых номера и даты одинаковые или номера одинаковые, а даты разные.

Мой вариант решения предполагает использование `exists c having count(*)>1`.

Comment: А зачем having и count(), вы бы свой запрос привели, что бы понятнее былочто требуется. мне кажется что достаточно exists с соответствующими проверками на равенство дат/номеров и _неравенство ID записей_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одинаковые номера

```
select deal_num, 
       count(1) 
from   t 
group  by deal_num 
having count(1) > 1
```

Одинаковые номера и даты

```
select deal_num, 
       dt, 
       count(1) 
from   t 
group  by deal_num, dt 
having count(1) > 1
```

Если нужна строка целиком:

```
select distinct t1.* 
from   t1 
left   join t2 
on     t1.deal_num=t2.deal_num 
and    t1.rowid!=t2.rowid
where  t2.deal_num is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
 from (select t.*, 
              count(*) over (partition by deal_num, dt) AS сnt1, 
              count(*) over (partition by deal_num) AS cnt2  
         from t) 
where cnt1>1 or cnt2>1
```